# Spring Boot 1.4.3 and @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring 4 application with a ControllerAdvice extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler that works fine when an exception rises.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionManager extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatus status,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {
        final ValidationErrors errors = getErrors(ex.getBindingResult());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errors, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }


    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(BindException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        final ValidationErrors errors = getErrors(ex.getBindingResult());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errors, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleValidationException(ValidationException ex) {
        log.warn("Validation error", ex);
        return ex.toResponseEntity();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleHttpClientErrorException(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex.getStatusCode());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleRootException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleException(request, ex);
    }

...
}
```

However, in case of unmarshaller exception, for exemple

```
Exception received: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class com.company.etc.v1.PojoResponse]: null; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 28; Attribute name "entResponse" associated with an element type "assetDocum" must be followed by the ' = ' character.]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.company.service.impl.SearchAsset.searchAssets(SearchAsset.java:42)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.java:133)
    ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "entResponse" associated with an element type "assetDocum" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    ... 131 common frames omitted
```

the exception is not catched!
It happens in a specific case, when a @RestController uses a service that calls an external endpoint. In my case, the external service returns an XML, and if it is broken (like in the exception above), then the `SAXParseException` is not catched and automagically converted as a 400 Bad Request with an empty body by spring. It is also not logged at all.

If, in my RestController, I add a method `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)`, this one is called and I can control the error sent back.

Is this normal? I was thinking that the ControllerAdvice could centralize all the exception handling, removing the need to have ExceptionHandler in each and every controller.

Comment: inside `handleRootExceptioninside ` method pass Throwable rather than Exception ex.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I've updated it to `@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity handleRootException(Throwable ex, WebRequest req) {
        log.error("Exception received: ", ex);
        return new ResponseEntity(ex, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }` but still not called, thus this exact code works if placed in the controller

Comment: You are not printing the entire exception stacktrace, the 'caused by' indicates it is a wrapped exception, not the top-level exception that is actually thrown.

Comment: @Gimby I've added the full stack when using the `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller. FYI the XML response is broken with a line return in a middle of a tag to provoke the exception.

Comment: So the actual catcheable exception is ```HttpMessageNotReadableException```; if you don't specifically handle it, the generic handleRootException() should be invoked. This is not happening?

Comment: No, it's not beeing invoked if placed in the ControllerAdvice. Worth mentioning that I use spring-boot-starter-actuator 1.4.3 in the pom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution: remove the `extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. Looks like it works better if you `@ControllerAdvice` doesn't extend anything.

Comment: Actually this is not a correct solution. It will indeed catch the `SAXParseException`, but then it does not catch anymore some others, like `MethodArgumentNotValidException` (I guess because the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid` is not overrided anymore

Comment: Yes indeed, event when defining a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` it's not catched. Well, still better than before...